# Rendering image using texSubImage2D in Haxe

Tags: webgl, haxe

I am learning how to stamp an image onto my canvas using Haxe and I have read that `texSubImage2D` should be the function I need to do the job.

I have read some documentation found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texSubImage2D) and thought I could implement what I was after by completing the following params:

```
void gl.texSubImage2D(target, level, xoffset, yoffset, format, type, HTMLImageElement? pixels);
```

This is what I did:

```
gl.texSubImage2D (cast fluid.dyeRenderTarget.writeToTexture, 0, Math.round(mouse.x), Math.round(mouse.y), gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, document.querySelector('img[src="images/myImage.jpg"]'));
```

However, when I try to build the project, I am getting the following errors:

```
src/Main.hx:571: characters 135-191 : js.html.Element should be Int
src/Main.hx:571: characters 135-191 : For function argument 'format'
```

When I went back to the docs, the format I have passed `gl.RGB` is an accepted param, so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: What Haxe version are you using?

Comment: @Gama11 3.2.1, just because the project I forked produces errors when using newer versions...

Comment: I see.. one more question before I write an answer, what's the type of `fluid.dyeRenderTarget.writeToTexture` that you need to cast it?

Comment: @Gama11 Looking through to the file writeToTexture is declared as so `public var writeToTexture         (default, null):GLTexture;` The writeToTexture is a wrapper around a regular webgl handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite reproduce the error message you're getting, I think the errors might have improved a bit in more in recent Haxe versions. Anyway, there's a few issues here:

- Firstly, by doing `gl.RGB` / `gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE`, you're trying to access static fields from an instance. I actually get a helpful error for this:

  > Cannot access static field RGB from a class instance

  While other languages allow this, [Haxe does not](https://haxe.org/manual/class-field-static.html), you have to access them through the *class name*. To fix this, simply prefix `js.html.webgl.RenderingContext`.
- Secondly, `querySelector()` returns a plain `js.html.Element`, which [none of the overloads](https://api.haxe.org/js/html/webgl/RenderingContext.html#texSubImage2D) accepts. They all want something more specific: `VideoElement`, `ImageElement` or `CanvasElement`. So you'd have to cast it first:

  ```
  var image:js.html.ImageElement = cast document.querySelector('img[src="images/myImage.jpg"]');
  ```
- Finally, it seems a bit suspicious that you'd need to cast the first parameter. Even if it works, there might be a nicer way of doing that with the wrapper you're using.

So in summary, the following should compile:

```
gl.texSubImage2D(cast fluid.dyeRenderTarget.writeToTexture, 0,
    Math.round(mouse.x), Math.round(mouse.y),
    RenderingContext.RGB, RenderingContext.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, everything makes sense, however, I still get two errors; `src/Main.hx:574: characters 162-167 : js.html.ImageElement should be Int` and `src/Main.hx:574: characters 162-167 : For function argument 'format'` I will have to investigate further as there is obviously more than meets the eye!

Comment: Found out the reason - I am using the snow library and that method doesn't exist! To fix I needed to simply change the method name to `gl.current_context.texSubImage2D();`